# Is there an equivalent of After Effect's "valueAtTime()" for drivers?

Tags: scripting, drivers

In After Effects you are allowed to use Expressions very similar to blender's drivers. In a very simple fashion you can get a property's value based on a given time like so:

```
 property.valueAtTime(1) // returns property.value at 1 seconds
```

In combination with a time variable, this method can come in pretty handy to stagger animations

```
property.valueAtTime(time - 1) //returns property.value at current time - 1 second
```

Now I was wondering if there is something similar I can use for drivers.

Comment: Both drivers and actions use an `FCurve`  Could try using the [`FCurve.evaluate(frame)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FCurve.html#bpy.types.FCurve.evaluate) method,  returns the value at a given frame.  Not sure re drivers, but have used this method to drive from baked sound fcurves with time shift.